# how can i play remote .mp3 file in my ios application?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play remote `.mp3 file`

but its giving the following error.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)
```

here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    isPlaying = NO;

/*   

 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]


pathForResource:@"Dar-e-Nabi-Per" ofType:@"mp3"]];

*/

    NSURL *url = [NSURL 

URLWithString:@"http://megdadhashem.wapego.ru/files/56727/tubidy_mp3_e2afc5.mp3"];

    NSError *error;

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]

                   initWithContentsOfURL:url

                   error:&error];

    if (error)

    {

        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",


              [error localizedDescription]);

 }

 else

 {

   audioPlayer.delegate = self;


   [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];


    }


}
```

Can anyone please guide me where i'm doing mistake

Comment: Mistake #1: your code is not readable. Mistake #2: you didn't google the error number.

Comment: @H2CO3 i google it but can't understand that error number ,
now can you give me the soloution thats wrong with my code ? and my code is readable .

Comment: Please, please, please, never do error checking like this. It is fundamentally broken, and against the Cocoa documentation. **Always** check the return value before testing the error pointer itself. http://blog.bignerdranch.com/360-an-nserror-error/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For steaming audio from a remote server, use AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPLayer.
[AVPlayer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Sample Code:

```
- (void)playSampleSong:(NSString *)iSongName {
    NSString *aSongURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://megdadhashem.wapego.ru/files/56727/tubidy_mp3_e2afc5.mp3"];
    // NSLog(@"Song URL : %@", aSongURL);

    AVPlayerItem *aPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aSongURL]];
    AVPlayer *anAudioStreamer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:aPlayerItem];
    [anAudioStreamer play];

    // Access Current Time
    NSTimeInterval aCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(anAudioStreamer.currentTime);

    // Access Duration
    NSTimeInterval aDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(anAudioStreamer.currentItem.asset.duration);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain which library to include to use this function

Comment: I have tried this code but unfortunately it didn't work, I have done some search, I recognized that I have to add remote controls code, please can you help!

Comment: For some reason i am not hearing anything

Answer (score 1):

Use this to play song from URL

```
NSData *songData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songData error:nil];
    self.player.numberOfLoops=0;
    _player.delegate=self;
    [_player prepareToPlay];
[_player play]
```

Comment: I tested this, and yes it works!

However, apple's documentation states regarding dataWithContentsOfURL: 
    
Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.   So I think dataTaskWithURL is reccomended.

Comment: This solution is synchronous, which is a bad idea. Also, it will only work on a simulator. On an actual device AVAudioPlayer throws an error with this code.