# How to Play And Stop an AVAudioPlayer in swift3?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I am developing an audio Player in swift and I need 2 buttons ( Play and Stop ) to control it. I have used the following code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 let urlstring = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
    print("the url = \(url!)")
    downloadFileFromURL(url: url!)

                             }

  func downloadFileFromURL(url:NSURL) {
    var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask
    downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (URL, response, error) -> Void in

        self.play(url: URL! as NSURL)

    })

    downloadTask.resume()

                                      }

 func play(url:NSURL) {
    print("playing \(url)")

    do {
        self.SoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
        SoundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        SoundPlayer.volume = 1.0
        SoundPlayer.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        //self.player = nil
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
    }

                       }

@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {

    SoundPlayer.play()

}


@IBAction func Stop(_ sender: Any) {

     SoundPlayer.stop()

}
```

Basically, when the user opens the app, the mp3 audio file starts automatically. Therefore I have created 2 additional buttons, Start and Stop and I want to control this Audio Player with them. Would you please advice me how to do it, because now they are not connected with the Audio Player and no action is performed when I click on them.

Comment: Did you check that SoundPlayer is not nil in the Play / Stop funcs?

Comment: They are nil I guess, but I do not know how to fix them

Comment: If they're nil, then I would assume you're losing reference to them some where. How are you defining the var SoundPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to just play the file while streaming it, get the Data from the `URL` from and then pass it to the `AVAudioPlayer`.

```
if let theURL = URL(string: "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3") {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: theURL){
        if let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(data: data) {
        print("Done")
        audioPlayer.play()
        } else {
        print("Noo")
        }

    }
}
```

`AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)` often fails to fetch data from remote location.

You can also check other options such as [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer) to play your file

[how can i play remote .mp3 file in my ios application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568917/how-can-i-play-remote-mp3-file-in-my-ios-application)